# What is the best way to store a client-independent program parameter?

Tags: abap

I need to store a list of transactions where my user exit wouldn't run. This list would preferably be client-independent (user exit needs same behaviour across clients). Using a database table may be overkill for a simple list ? Variants has been suggested but the client-independent table for variants is obsolete.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: A database table for this is not an overkill, but the right solution with the necessary flexibility.

Comment: I agree with József, a database table would be the clean solution. In addition, this solution allows you to create a maintenance UI without the need of programming. You could add additional key fields to identify the program, so you could use this table as some sort of client independent key-value-store for other programs as well.

Comment: If you don't want to create a database table i could imaging the following hacks:
Store the data in a server-side file (be careful, there may be multiple application servers and you need to make sure they share this file), store the transaction codes in a CTS piece list with a specific name (SE01) or store your data in a dummy report consisting of comments only and retrieve then using READ REPORT. For sure there are lots of other hacks, but still i would recommend the database table.

Answer (score 4):

Just if you don't want to create a new table, ECC has a special transaction for that task: **STVARV/STVARVC**.

[Defining and maintaining Selection Variables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6a49d1604ffc4b908f9f78fba3824187/6.06.20/en-US/7797d7531a4d414de10000000a174cb4.html)

It serves for creating and maintaining business-specific variants, variables, transactional parameters and so on.

After the release 6.40 changes have been introduced (notes [1994216](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1994216), [770084](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/770084), [557314](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/557314) ) that made TVARV obsolete and left only client-specific TVARV**C**, however this shouldn't make you frustrated.

Though you cannot use TVARVC tcode for maintaining records, nothings prevents you from bypassing this stupid limitation and create entries in `TVARV` manually, this table is client-independent.

Also, client-specific `TVARVC` table has `CLIE_INDEP` field that probably serves for the similar purpose

[image]

however I didn't test if this flag functions properly, it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `CLIE_INDEP` field exists in the database but not in the maintenance transaction STVARV unfortunately. This transaction only gives the possibility to add the modifications to a transport request. I appreciate your answer but I can't mark it as accepted because it doesn't fill the requirement of client-independence.